# How to link on local filesystem with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I'd like to use [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) to share a page that cannot be served anywhere. I need to share this information using sync clients (Dropbox, Google Drive, WorkDocs, etc) and i'd like the links on the pages to work, regardless of the path where they are synced.

When i generate a new jekykll site with `jekyll new somesite`, then build with `jekyll build`, then open `index.html` from the filesystem, the links are broken because they are absolute.

For example, the href to the sample "Welcome to Jekyll" is generated as `"/jekyll/update/2015/09/12/welcome-to-jekyll.html"` and thus opens to `"file:///jekyll/update/2015/09/12/welcome-to-jekyll.html"` on my browser.

If it would generate us relative links, such as `"jekyll/update/2015/09/12/welcome-to-jekyll.html"`, they would open fine regardless of the system or path they are opened from.

Would it be possible to change jekyll to use relative links instad of the default absolute links?

Comment: Please comment before downvoting, if that question is bad i'd like to know why...

Comment: If you have a document on Dropox or google drive, you have a sharing link. So, where is there problem ?

Comment: Thank you, clarification added.

Answer (score 0):

#### A fast and dirty way

If your page is in the root of the website (e.g. index.html), you could create relative links to posts using liquid filters, e.g.:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <a href="{{ post.url | replace_first:'/','' }}">{{post.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But, if you want relative links from every possible page in you site, I think that the only solution is to write a custom liquid filter that generate a relative link considering the current page location and the link location.

#### A clean way

Another (and more clean) way could be to use different `_config.yml` files for every destination. Here you can config each `host` and `permalink` structure to match the destination.

E.g. to serve your jekyll blog from http://example.com/my/subdir/blog:

```
# _config-example-com.yml
host: example.com
permalink: /my/subdir/blog/:year/:month/:title
```

Then build your blog using:

```
jekyll build --config _config-example-com.yml
```

If you have X targets, you could use a script to run jekyll X times (using every time a different config file) and then copy every output from `_site` to another directory, or upload directly where you want.

Comment: As i don't know how many targets i'll have, or any information on them, the fast and dirty would be better and seems to do the trick. Thank you very much!